# Need help in FFMPEG with AES encryption

Tags: ffmpeg, aes, media, http-live-streaming

I want to segment a video file, create a playlist, encrypt it with AES 128 bit and stream it and play it using FFMPEG on windows platform.
I am able to segment the video file, create playlist. But i need help with AES encryption.

Below is the command i am using:

```
ffmpeg -i C:\Videos\Sample.mp4 -hls_time 30 -hls_key_info_file file.keyinfo -hls_segment_filename C:\Videos\Output\file%03d.ts C:\Videos\Output\out.m3u8
```

In my Output directory, I have 15 segmented video files with .ts extension(file000.ts - file014.ts) and 1 playlist file (out.m3u8).

Now out.m3u8 file is as below:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:38
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:10
#EXTINF:28.653622,
file010.ts
#EXTINF:29.863167,
file011.ts
#EXTINF:37.412378,
file012.ts
#EXTINF:22.814456,
file013.ts
#EXTINF:16.057711,
file014.ts
#EXT-X-ENDLIST
```

Why is out.m3u8 file showing only file010.ts - file014.ts ? 
Why is is not encrypting all the files? 
What about the remaining files ?
What am i missing ?

Comment: `-hls_playlist_type vod` to keep all the segments

Comment: @aergistal - It worked !! Thank you

Comment: Now i need one more thing. Currently i am encrypting all my media segments with a single key. How can i go about if i want to encrypt every 10 segments with a new key ?

Comment: **Changes to key_info_file will result in segment encryption with the new key/IV and an entry in the playlist for the new key URI/IV.** It's all in the [documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#hls-1), it begs to be read.

Comment: @aergistal - In mediafilesegmenter there is -key-rotation-period parameter using which this can be done. But with ffmpeg how do i do this ? i have multiple keys but how can i change key_info_file after every x segments ?